# Javascript issue in button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have designed a page on which I have used `button`. When the button is clicked, `onClick` event opens the `modal`, but only for the first time, later clicks don't open the `modal`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myBtn3").click(function(){
    $("#myModal3").modal({backdrop: "static"});
});



<center><button type="button" name="skills" class="btn btn-primary" id="myBtn3">More Details</button></center>
```

Comment: There is seems to be all right with your code. Here is working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/228/) . In HTML you posted there is only button but no modal. The error may be in how hoy add modal to the page. Add this part  to the question description.

Comment: Hii, the code i have written in model   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog"> <div class="modal-dialog"> <div class="modal-content">            <div class="modal-header">     <a type="button" class="popup-close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
                                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Education details</h4>    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <div class="form-group">

Comment: It is better to add HTML directly into the question. Also at first glance your HTML is invalid Some closing div tags are absent.